# How to use _.debounce correctly?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash, debouncing

### Background

Imagine you have an app where you receive tons of info when you make a request. In my app about restaurants, I want to calculate the average price of all menus every time I get a request containing several restaurants:

```
var avg = menus => {
  const sum = menus.reduce( ( sum, currMenu ) => currMenu.price + sum , 0);
  console.log( sum / menus.length );
};
```

### Our Solution

The problem is that I get so many restaurants my app starts to lag! Solution? Well, since the user doesn't care to see the updated average every 0.001 ms we decided to use debounce to show an updated average every 100ms or so:

`var debounceAvg = _.debounce( avg, 100 );`

For an article on how debounce works have a read at here:

- https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

### Problem

So, now we have a debounce function. To test it I have a test function:

```
var myMenus = [ { price: 1 }, { price: 2 }, { price: 3 } ];

var timer = setInterval( params => {
    console.log("executing timer");
    debounceAvg(params);
}, 20, myMenus );

setTimeout( () => { clearInterval(timer) }, 5000);
```

This function should print to the log the avg price of all menus every 100ms even though it is being invoked every 20ms. However I only end up with 2 logs containing the avg price - the first and the last.

### Question

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're asking the function to fire on the *leading edge* of the wait period, so it'll always fire as soon as it's called.

Comment: The loop isn't the best way to test debouncing. The whole thing executes in moment.

Comment: @Pointy The first call will execute immediately. The second one will have to wait 100 ms.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That is why I have a very very big number. But the result never changes ....

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix no, that's not how it works as far as I can tell from the source. *edit* well maybe you're right but I thing Mr. Spinks's answer is the real story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually logging outside your debounce function. So your logging is happening every time through the loop. That's why you are getting all those zeros.
You can either do your logging inside your debounce function (you could pass it in as a parameter), or check for a change in your loop.

Here is a possible implementation of passing your function in as a param for testing. I'm not sure that I fully understand your logic in the functions, but this should at least get you started:

```
var val = 0;
avg = function(menus, callback) {
  val = menus.reduce( ( sum, currMenu) => currMenu.price + sum , 0)) / menus.length;
  callback();
  return val;
}
var testDebounce = iterations => {
    const myMenus = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ) {
        myMenus.push( { price: i } );
        debounceAvg(aparts, function() {
          console.log(val);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ? I am confused and could use an example.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix `for(10000 iterations) { console.log(something); }` see?

Comment: Can you tell me what your debounceAvg function is? I have a hard time making your example work.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix what he's saying is that whether the debounced version of your function actually runs your *real* function or not, it still returns synchronously. Your loop calls `console.log()` on each iteration.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix, Check my updated answer. Your `debounceAvg` should be unchanged. Also, I made `val` global just for this test.

Comment: The key here, as others have pointed out, is that your `console.log` call is happening inside your loop, not inside your debounced function.

Comment: I Have updated my post and refactored my question/code now. I hope it is more clear as I am still in need of assistance.